# How to make a double className inside of an single component in a Styled Component

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I try to make this code

style.css

```
.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s ease;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

and

```
<div
  className={index === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'}
  key={index}
>
  {index === current && (
    <img src={slide.image} alt='travel image' className='image' />
  )}
</div>
```

I hope you guys can help me answer it in styled components, or at least how to use the css so that it can be used as the transition.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but I think you want to render your `className` conditionally right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the component as a styled-component and then have the values change according to an `isActive` prop.

```
const Slide = styled.div`
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.$isActive ? 1 : 0)};
  transition-duration: ${(props) => (props.$isActive ? "1s" : "1s ease")};
  transform: ${(props) => (props.$isActive ? "scale(1.08)" : "inherit")};
`;
```

```
<Slide $isActive>Hello World!</Slide>
// or
// <Slide $isActive={true|false}>Hello World!</Slide>
```

Comment: should I add something like
const Slide = styled.div<Props> here because I was using a typescript here

Comment: Yep, add them something like: type SlideProps = {
  $isActive: boolean;
};

const Slide = styled.div<SlideProps>